Proving a proposition on Lie derivatives of differential forms.

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, $V\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, and
$\omega$, $\eta \in \Omega^*(M)$. Then,
$$\mathscr{L}_V(\omega\wedge\eta)=(\mathscr{L}_V\omega)\wedge \eta
 +\omega\wedge (\mathscr{L}_V\eta)$$

I made an attempt to prove this.
Proof \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
            &\mathscr{L}_V(\omega\wedge\eta)=(\mathscr{L}_V\omega)\wedge(\mathscr{L}_V\eta)\\
            & =\big[ V\lrcorner (\text{d}\omega)+\text{d}(V\lrcorner \omega)\big]\wedge \big[ V\lrcorner \text{d}\eta+\text{d}(V\lrcorner\eta)\big]\\
            & = \big[ i_V(\text{d}\omega) +\text{d}(i_V\omega)\big]\wedge \big[ i_V(\text{d}\eta)+\text{d}(i_V\eta)\big]\\
            & = \big[ \underbrace{\text{d}\omega(v,\omega_1,\dots,\omega_{k-1})}_{\mathscr{L}\omega}+\underbrace{\text{d}\big(\omega(v,w_1,\dots,w_{k-1})\big)}_{\omega}\big]\wedge \\
            &\big[ \underbrace{\text{d}\eta(v,\eta_1,\dots,\eta_{k-1})}_{\mathscr{L}\eta}+\underbrace{\text{d}\big(\eta(v,w_1,\dots,w_{k-1})\big)}_{\eta}\big]\\
            & = \big[\mathscr{L}_V\omega+\omega\big]\wedge\big[\mathscr{L}_V\eta+\eta\big]\\
            & =\big(\mathscr{L}_V\omega\big)\wedge\eta+\omega\wedge\big(\mathscr{L}_V\eta\big)
        \end{split}
    \end{equation}
However, here I have a problem when $\omega\wedge\eta$ must become zero to satisfy the proposition. The wedge product of the two Lie derivatives on the two tensors is zero, since that follows the rule $dx_i\wedge dx_i=0$, but $\omega\wedge\eta\ne0$. Any ideas what is the final transition to the answer?
Thanks
UPDATE
We use Cartan's magic formula on $\omega\wedge\eta$ and obtain
$$ \mathscr{L}_V(\omega\wedge\eta)=V\lrcorner \big(\text{d}(\omega\wedge\eta)\big)+\text{d}(V\lrcorner f)) $$
$$\mathscr{L}_V(\omega\wedge\eta)=\big[ i_V(\text{d}(\omega\wedge\eta) +\text{d}(i_V(\omega\wedge\eta)\big]+\mathscr{L}_Vf$$
Now we use the properties of the exterior derivative and obtain:
$$\mathscr{L}_V(\omega\wedge\eta)=\big[i_V\big(\text{d}\omega\wedge\eta+(-1)^k\omega\wedge\text{d}\eta\big)+\text{d}\big(i_V(\text{d}\omega\wedge\eta+(-1)^k\omega\wedge\text{d}\eta)\big)\big]+\mathscr{L}_Vf
 $$

The very first equality you wrote is false: in general, $L_V(\omega\wedge\eta) \neq (L_V\omega)\wedge(L_V\eta)$. Use directly Cartan's magic formula on $\omega\wedge\eta$ and use the (graded)-commutation relations for the interior product $i_V$ and the exterior differential $d$.

@Didier Thanks! Just a note: With Cartan's formula: $$\mathscr{L}_V(\omega)=V\lrcorner (\text{d}\omega)+\text{d}(V\lrcorner f)) $$
$$ \mathscr{L}_V(\eta)=V\lrcorner (\text{d}\eta)+\text{d}(V\lrcorner f)) $$
can I wedge these two blocks together?

Not sure what your question is (and what $f$ is actually). Anyway, the wedge product is distributive over the addition ($(\alpha + \beta) \wedge (\gamma + \delta) = \alpha\wedge \gamma + \alpha \wedge \delta + \beta \wedge \gamma + \beta \wedge \delta$)

What  I meant is that Cartan's formula is for a single tensor, not for the wedge of two tensors. So I am not sure how to combine the two given Cartan's forms for the wedge product of $\omega$ and $\eta$. Using your point that we cannot obtain the very first quality in the OP, I assume this is valid also for Cartan's forms. So having $\mathscr{L}_V(\omega\wedge\eta)$ and $\mathscr{L}_V(\omega)$ and $\mathscr{L}_V(\eta)$ by Cartan's formula, how can I use this to go to the next step? Thanks

$\omega \wedge \eta$ is a single tensor, and you can apply $L_V$, $d$ and $i_V$ to it. You can play with the definition of the wedge product to obtain a formula relating $i_V(\omega\wedge\eta)$, $(i_V \omega) \wedge \eta$ and $\omega\wedge (i_V\eta)$. The formula relating $d(\omega\wedge\eta)$, $(d\omega)\wedge \eta$  and $\omega\wedge(d\omega)$ is well known

Ok, I will try to find these definitions in Lee's. Thanks

No I meant to use $\omega\wedge\eta = \omega\otimes \eta - \eta \otimes \omega$ for $\omega,\eta$ 1-forms (and similar things for higher degree forms), and that $d(\omega\wedge\eta) = d\omega \wedge \eta + (-1)^{\deg \omega} \omega \wedge d\eta$ for any differential forms

I just found it, yes, it is the property of the exterior derivative (as you said). Thanks

@Didier I think it is getting better, see the update, but there is still something strange.

What even is $f$?

@Didier $f$ is given in Lee's book, it is  just "f". It sounds awfully simple, but I think if you set it to zero, it can work.

Can you point at the explicit Proposition in Lee's book you are referring to? I'll check in my personal copy, I think you might be confusing two different things

On p 372, I used (14.32) and represented the first term on the RHS in 14.32 with the form given in the top equation on p.373. So  $$V\lrcorner(\text{d}\omega)\to V\lrcorner(\text{d}f)$$

There is no $f$ in (14.32), and on the equation on the top of p. 373, there is no $\omega$. Careful when mixing these things. There is no universal $f$ and the one in your attempt simply makes no sense. You are only given $\omega$ and $\eta$, and any attempt to answer this should only use $\omega$ and $\eta$.

@Didier thanks, now I see that was a stupid mixup. Thanks

Cartan's magic formula says that for any differential form $\alpha$ and any vector field $X$, one has
$$
L_X\alpha = d(\iota_X\alpha) + \iota_X(d\alpha).
$$
In particular, if $\alpha = \omega\wedge\eta$, then
$$
L_X(\omega\wedge\eta) = d(\iota_X(\omega\wedge\eta)) + \iota_X(d(\omega\wedge\eta)).
$$
I will need to use the following technology: if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are differential forms, then
$$
d(\alpha\wedge\beta)
= (d\alpha)\wedge\beta + (-1)^{\deg\alpha}\alpha\wedge(d\beta)
$$
and, if moreover $X$ is a vector field,
$$
\iota_X(\alpha\wedge\beta)
= (\iota_X\alpha)\wedge\beta + (-1)^{\deg\alpha}\alpha\wedge(\iota_X\beta)
$$
First, one has
$$
\iota_X(\omega\wedge\eta) = (\iota_X\omega)\wedge\eta + (-1)^{\deg \omega}\omega\wedge(\iota_X\eta),
$$
and thus
\begin{align}
d(\iota_X(\omega\wedge\eta))
&= d((\iota_X\omega)\wedge\eta + (-1)^{\deg \omega}\omega\wedge(\iota_X\eta)) \\
&= d((\iota_X\omega)\wedge\eta) + (-1)^{\deg\omega}d(\omega\wedge(\iota_X\eta)) \\
&= (d(\iota_X\omega))\wedge \eta + (-1)^{\deg \iota_X\omega} (\iota_X\omega)\wedge(d\eta) \\
&\quad + (-1)^{\deg\omega}((d\omega)\wedge(\iota_X\eta) + (-1)^{\deg\omega} \omega \wedge (d(\iota_X\eta))) \\
&= (d(\iota_X\omega))\wedge \eta+ \omega\wedge(d(\iota_X\eta)) \\
&\quad -(-1)^{\deg\omega}(\iota_X\omega)\wedge(d\eta) + (-1)^{\deg \omega}(d\omega)\wedge(\iota_X\eta).
\end{align}
For the last equality, I have used the fact that $\deg\iota_X\omega = \deg\omega -1$, so that $(-1)^{\deg\iota_X\omega} = -(-1)^{\deg\omega}$.
Second, one has
$$
d(\omega\wedge\eta)
= (d\omega)\wedge\eta + (-1)^{\deg\omega} \omega\wedge(d\eta),
$$
and thus
\begin{align}
\iota_X(d(\omega\wedge\eta))
&= \iota_X((d\omega)\wedge\eta + (-1)^{\deg\omega} \omega\wedge(d\eta)) \\
&= \iota_X((d\omega)\wedge\eta) + (-1)^{\deg\omega} \iota_X(\omega\wedge(d\eta)) \\
&= (\iota_X(d\omega))\wedge \eta + (-1)^{\deg d\omega} (d\omega)\wedge(\iota_X\eta) \\
&\quad + (-1)^{\deg\omega}((\iota_X\omega)\wedge(d\eta) + (-1)^{\deg\omega}\omega\wedge(\iota_X(d\eta))) \\
&= (\iota_X(d\omega))\wedge\eta + \omega\wedge(\iota_X(d\eta)) \\
&\quad -(-1)^{\deg\omega}(d\omega)\wedge(\iota_X\eta) + (-1)^{\deg\omega}(\iota_X\omega)\wedge(d\eta).
\end{align}
For the last equality, I have used the fact that $\deg d\omega = \deg\omega +1$, so that $(-1)^{\deg d\omega} = -(-1)^{\deg\omega}$.
Finally, noticing the obvious cancellations, one obtains
\begin{align}
L_X(\omega\wedge\eta)
&= (d(\iota_X\omega))\wedge \eta+ \omega\wedge(d(\iota_X\eta)) \\
&\quad + (\iota_X(d\omega))\wedge\eta + \omega\wedge(\iota_X(d\eta)) \\
&= (d(\iota_X\omega)+ \iota_X(d\omega))\wedge \eta + \omega\wedge(d(\iota_X\eta) + \iota_X(d\eta)) \\
&= (L_X\omega)\wedge\eta + \omega\wedge(L_X\eta).
\end{align}
For the last equality, I have used Cartan's magic formula for $\omega$ and $\eta$ respectively.

Thanks  for this Didier, I will study this closely tomorrow! All the best
